# Fail to create postgres extensions through bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, postgresql-9.3

launched a postgres db within docker container and want to install extensions afterwards with following script:

```
su postgres sh -c "psql -U postgres <<EOSQL
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
EOSQL"

trap "echo \"Sending SIGTERM to postgres\"; killall -s SIGTERM postgres" SIGTERM

su postgres sh -c "$POSTGRES -D $DATADIR -c config_file=$CONF" &
wait $!
```

but it does nothing, in the extension list only one default plpgsql is installed.

but if I enter container with

```
docker exec -it osm-database bash
```

and run the following in cli in sequence

```
su postgres
psql -U postgres
create extension hstore;
```

then I can see from pgAdmin hstore is successfully installed